# Human Readable ydn-db Sources

Tags: ydn-db

Where I can Found the last sources with human readable format javascript code? I'm trying to solve one problem but I can't understand some code. I download the code [here](http://download.yathit.com/) but I don't know what file is for me.

Comment: if your aim is to learn javascript you can look here : http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: This is great resource but I need is to know how I can debug this project [link](http://git.yathit.com/ydn-db/wiki/Home)

Comment: sorry still i couldnt understand your aim

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a location on the Internet that displays the source code for a certain program. Finding a URL has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

Have you look at [source](http://git.yathit.com/ydn-db/src) in the project repo?